# Handshake Failure Installing LOEclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, libreoffice

Attempting to install the LOEclipse plugin to develop extensions using Eclipse. However, I receive the following error from the marketplace:

> Unable to read repository at http://eclipse-plugins.libreoffice.or.... Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

> java -version openjdk version "11.0.3-ojdkbuild" 2019-04-16 LTS OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.3-ojdkbuild+7-LTS) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.3-ojdkbuild+7-LTS, mixed mode)

> OS: Windows 10

> Eclipse Version :2020-09 (4.17.0) Build 20200910-1200

I'd really appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up reinstalling both LibreOffice and the LibreOffice SDK and this fixed the issue.